# Simple webserver for c++

Tags: c++, json, http

My c++ server-app needs to have a port 80 open to output some json 
(for other web-apps to see the status)

I saw a few web-server that i can spwan from a c++ class, but they seem rather complicated. I don't need any request/response, just a string that i time by time update and that is shown on port 80 then.

My server-app is running in a loop, so i guess this should be a thread that gets the string update every here and then. Please point me in the right direction is i am totally wrong in my planning/thinking.

Comment: There's no such thing as _"a string that i time by time update and that is shown on port 80 then."_. You can't _display_ __anything__ on a _port_. You can't also put a string there, since a port isn't a container. it's a __communication mechanism__. You can however handle requests sent to that particular port, thus you __do__ need a request/response system. A very simple one tho.

Comment: [Tntnet](http://www.tntnet.org/) is an open-source C++ based web-server, perhaps it can serve as an inspiration.

Comment: HTTP is a request response protocol, how could you say that you don't need any request/resonse? I hope you meant http when you said 'webserver'

Comment: @sanjayk79: I think 6502 got what i need. I meant that i don't need to have a show different content as a response, a standard response for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be to use a webserver to serve a static file and having your application to update the content when needed.

Just pay attention on the configuration of the server to inform the clients that the content should not be cached.

Another somewhat important part is to create a new file and move it to the destination (published) location once the file is complete (to avoid clients to download a partial file that could be invalid).

Comment: True, i was not thinking about that, that seems awesome, i don't need to deal with any server logic myself then :-) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (or perhaps [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/)) within your C++ application.

Notice that `libonion` usually runs the web service in some other thread, so you need to take care of synchronization (e.g. using mutexes), and is also able to serve static content and static files.